# Stop Playing Audio when come back to View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, avfoundation

I am playing audio from playlist in my app. I am using following code in viewDidLoad function:-

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:FeedLink];
    NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =  0;
```

On Play button it play the audio and it also playing fine in background or when i go to another class.

The problem is when i came back to this view controller and select another audio then the previous Playing audio is not stopped.  and both are Playing simultaneously.

Can any one help me in this that when i came back to viewDidLoad from anther view controller it stop the playing audio and only play one at a time. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In viewwillappear of the class where you are playing the audio use below code.then playing stopped when you back to that class.

```
-(void)viewwillappear{
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before playing any Audio file add a check of wether any Audio file is playing on or not.

Add below code for that.

```
if(audioPlayer.isPlaying){
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Then after play your next audio file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried this but it never come in this condition. i think every time it creates a new instance. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Put break point & see wether memory is there in audioPlayer object or not

Comment: Sorry @Nilesh, i don't know how to check memory of object.

Comment: I have already added code above in question. every time when i came back to view controller url of audio is changed and it play new audio. but previous one is also playing with new one.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Replace your code with my code & see wether its works at your end or not..

Comment: No, It does not solve the problem. still more than one audio is playing

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the code. So that I can solve it share updated code with you again.

Comment: if(audioPlayer.isPlaying){
[audioPlayer stop];
}   compiler never come in this condition.

Comment: I have used just above code in viewDidLoad. there is nothing else to Play audio.I have one anther view Controller from where i select audio and redirect to this view controller for Playing.